# conditionally assigning values for union types

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript and am stuck on how to dynamically assign values to a union type:

```
type Labs = (name === 'dakota') ? 'fruit' | 'veg' : 'plow' | 'field' | 'till';
```

I keep getting this error that "*name* refers to a **value** but is being used as a **type**".

**To be clear, what I want to do is limit the valid values of type `Lab`:**

```
type Labs = 'fruit' | 'veg'
// if name === 'dakota', otherwise:
type Labs = 'plow' | 'field' | 'till'
```

---

I have also tried to use a function that returns the correct type:

```
function getLabType<Type>(arg: string): Type {
  if (arg === 'dakota') {
    type A = 'fruit' | 'veg';
    return A
  }
  type B = 'plow' | 'field' | 'till'
  return B
}

type Lab = getLabType('dakota')
```

With the function I get a similar warning about `A` and `B` only referring to types but being used as values.

How can I conditionally assign values to a union type? Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: It's not too clear what you are trying to accomplish with this so we might be able to provide better recommendations if you show us the use case. However you can try making the `Labs` type generic: `type Labs<T extends string> = T extends "dakota" ? "fruit" | "veg" : "plow" | "field" | "till"`, which seems to be what you were trying to do in that first snippet.

Comment: @CRice, I am trying to limit the set of string literals that a value is allowed to be. So if my condition passes, then I want to restrict the values to 'fruit' | 'veg', otherwise restrict to 'plow' | 'field' | 'till'.

Comment: I see. In that case, Guerric P has an excellent answer. Does that solution work for you?

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this with [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQDIEMBGAVATwAdUAePRVADylTABMBnRRqAJxjGQD4AKLNsgBciPAEoRFarQbMA5PSwBrOFCxzEAfkRzgbEDCgaAPjoBuqZBpFyiAGzgB3EzuAxUd%20i7mw7duQBQoJCwCCjo2PjEqPyCIqwcXBIs7JzIiADeAYg5iDDAiLHpALylOooqanJimdm59WzoIGxIuvqGcgDcdTkAvj2IjVDNrW4eXt39ARAIrIh6BlAA8mwAapaIxeGYuIQkvArKqupi3TNgc-ZOAGLunit4MH6b25F7MXKqABaobNWdQA) and [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```
function getLabType<T extends string>(arg: T): T extends 'dakota' ? 'fruit' | 'veg' : 'plow' | 'field' | 'till'
function getLabType(arg: string): string {
    if (arg === 'dakota') {
        return 'fruit';
    }
    return 'field';
}

const fruitOrVeg = getLabType('dakota');
const plowFieldOrTill = getLabType('other');
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQDIEMBGAVATwAdUAePRVADylTABMBnRRqAJxjGQD4AKLNsgBciPAEoRFarQbMA5PSwBrOFCxzEAfkRzgbEDCgaAPjoBuqZBpFyiAGzgB3EzuAxUd%20i7mw7duQBQoJCwCCjo2PjEqPyCIqwcXBIs7JzIiADeAYg5iDDAiLHpALylOooqanJimdm59WzoIGxIuvqGcgDcdTkAvj2IjVDNrW4eXt39ARAIrIh6BlAA8mwAapaIxeGYuIQkvArKqupi3TNgc-ZOAGLunit4MH6b25F7MXKqABaobNWdQA)

If you only need a type (no JavaScript) then do this:

```
type Labs<T> = T extends 'dakota' ? 'fruit' | 'veg' : 'plow' | 'field' | 'till';
```

Then use it like `Labs<typeof name>` or whatever else.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghgIwM4B4AqA+KBeKaoQAewEAdgCZJQDk5cA1gPbBzVQD8NAZgE4CuAS2BsAPjQBuEAOZsAXDTAAbRgHdR3AREXl11YAMWLqAbgBQp8hADGiuD2hXGpJMCgkX8lzwGkpZ0wJcUAAU7q7YETR0TCzUAJRQAN6mUKlu4NBoEC44sIiooJCMQWEYZgC+BIpI0Mlp6ZB42eF5yCiFEMVuzWWm5UA)

Comment: This is great. Question: what is the meaning of `<typeof name>`. Wouldn't I want to send the actual value of name? That is, send the actual string?

Comment: No, you should not confuse **types** and **values**. Types are entirely erased from the runnable (JavaScript) code while values remain. When writing a type, we can infer types from values with the `typeof` keyword, but we can't use values as is. This implies that you have written statically analyzable code that infers the right type for your `name` variable, as I did in my playground example with an `if`

Comment: To explain further why your initial attempt didn't work, you tried to return a **type** (non-existent in runtime code) from a JavaScript **function**. This kind of construct will never work.

Comment: In my case, I think `typeof name` will return `string`, at least that is what javascript would do. So how will the generic type (your second solution) test for the string 'dakota' if it is passed 'string'?

Comment: If your code does not allow TypeScript to narrow the `name` type to `'dakota'` or something else, then there is no solution.